# How to merge two lists in parallel in R?

Tags: r, merge

I'm asking to how to merge two lists in parallel, not orderly append as below codes.

For example,

```
A <- list(c(1,2,3), c(3,4,5), c(6,7,8))

B <- list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("d", "e", "f"), c("g", "h", "i"))
```

As results,

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 3 4 5

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "d" "e" "f"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 6 7 8

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "g" "h" "i"
```

Comment: What are you trying to get as the output?

Comment: With `purrr`, `map2(A, B, list)` (equivalent to the answer below) or `list(A, B) %>% transpose()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using  `Map` simply:

```
   Map(list,A,B)
```

Answer (score 0):

A longer approach (not recursive yet, up to second level merging):

```
A <- list(c(1,2,3), c(3,4,5), c(6,7,8))

B <- list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("d", "e", "f"), c("g", "h", "i"))

mergepar <- function(x = A, y = B) { # merge two lists in parallel
    ln <- max(length(x), length(y)) # max length
    newlist <- as.list(rep(NA, ln)) # empty list of max length

    for (i in 1:ln) { # for1, across length
        # two level subsetting (first with [ and then [[, so no subscript out of bound error) and lapply
        newlist[[i]] <- lapply(list(A, B), function(x) "[["("["(x, i), 1)) 
    }

    return(newlist)
}
```

Comment: Keen eyes @rich-scriven, congrats! Corrected with some additional touch